# Bitcoin has been unconfirmed for over 9 hours now am scared I don’t know what to fo

Tags: blockchain

I sent a total of about $540 worth of bTC to another account and it’s still unconfirmed for over 9 hours now the fee was about $0.29

Please what do I do am so sad

Answer (score 1):

Just wait, your fee is low, so you have a low priority. It will eventually get trough.